# How to do Mobile App Caching?

Tags: android, ios, caching, mobile

I'm looking for mobile app caching. How to manage caching process?How do I cache webservice response or image?  Is there any detailed resource(book, video or cheetsheet) for this?

Comment: Google `NSUrlCache`.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I want to build cache mechanism like facebook. But I dont know how to do and where start from

Comment: You can think this problem as pattern problem. What are patterns of caching?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this iOS Library](https://bitbucket.org/grsomani/asyncloader/)  which I had created as an assignment some time back.

I had made this by customizing the code for AsyncImageView, credits to them. Though AsyncImageView is meant for Images while my assignment was for any kind of file.

You can also refer AsyncImageView for getting an idea.